# I want to integrate LDAP authentication in Django, but missing some configuration I guess

Tags: django, authentication, ldap

I want to integrate LDAP authentication in Django, but even authentication is not happening i.e even after providing the correct LDAP credentials the user details in the Django admin panel the user details are not getting stored in the Django user model.

Here's my setttings.py file in Django

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldaps://xxxxxx:636'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = 'CN=xxxxx,OU=Service,OU=Accounts,OU=SF_SAP,DC=sf,DC=priv'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'xxxxxxxx'
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch('OU=User,OU=Accounts,OU=SF_SAP, DC=sf,DC=priv',ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(CN=%(user)s)')

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
        "first_name": "givenName",
        "last_name": "sn",
        "email": "mail",
        "username": "uid",
        "password": "userPassword",
}
AUTH_LDAP_PROFILE_ATTR_MAP = {
        "home_directory": "homeDirectory"
}
AUTH_LDAP_ALWAYS_UPDATE_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
        'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)
```

I enabled logging for LDAP and I see the following error in the logs

```
Binding as CN=xxxxxxxxx,OU=Service,OU=Accounts,OU=SF_SAP,DC=sf,DC=priv
Caught LDAPError while authenticating xxxxxx: SERVER_DOWN({'result': -1, 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server", 'ctrls': [], 'info': 'error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed (unable to get local issuer certificate)'})
```

Question: Where does django look for the trusted certificates?

Comment: Please, share you `LDAPBackend` code.

Comment: you mean django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend? this is part of a library right

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that the search filter is wrong : according to the user attribute map, `username` maps to `uid`, if it's correct the search filter should be `'(uid=%(user)s)'` :

```py
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(
  'OU=User,OU=Accounts,OU=SF_SAP, DC=sf,DC=priv', ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, '(uid=%(user)s)'
)
```

But it could be the contrary (hard to know without a user dn example) : if the authentication works but user provisioning doesn't, then fix the mapping : `"username": "cn"`.

You might also want to double check that all users you are trying to authenticate belong to the specified subtree `'OU=User,OU=Accounts,OU=SF_SAP, DC=sf,DC=priv'`.

Comment: distinguishedName: CN=xxxxx,OU=User,OU=Accounts,OU=SF_SAP,DC=sf,DC=priv

This is one example of a DN